# circuitikz wrongly displays european voltages

Tags: positioning, circuitikz

The voltages arrows are misplaced with respect to the components, in this case a resistor.

```
 \begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \ctikzset { bipoles/length=1cm}
    \begin{circuitikz} [european ,scale=0.65]
        \draw
        (5,0) to[short]
        (0,0) to[V = $V_{supply}$] 
        (0,3) to[generic=${Shunt}$]
        (5,3);
        \draw
        (5,0) to[R,mirror,v>=$v_{o}$,i<=$i_o$] (5,3);
        \draw (6,0) to[R,mirror,v>=$v_{o}$,i<=$i_o$] (8,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
    \label{fig:OI_model}
    \caption{The Output Impedance Model for SCCs. }
  \end{figure}
```

See the result:

[image: Votlage arrows and labels are wrong]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \ctikzset{bipoles/length=1cm}
    \begin{circuitikz} [european]
        \draw
        (5,0) to[short]
        (0,0) to[V = $V_{supply}$]
        (0,3) to[generic=${Shunt}$]
        (5,3);
        \draw
        (5,0) to[R,v^<=$v_{o}$,i<=$i_o$] (5,3);
        \draw (6,0) to[R,v^<=$v_{o}$,i<=$i_o$] (8,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
    \label{fig:OI_model}
    \caption{The Output Impedance Model for SCCs. }
  \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

I have removed `mirror` (which doesn't work) and used `v^` instead.

Comment: Just what I need! Thanx!